# IBM Worklight 6.0 - How to deploy worklight app into Worklight Server?

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst, worklight-studio, worklight-server

Is it possible to deploy an app to external Worklight server instance when I don't have the IBM  Worklight Server installed on my computer ?. Is there any alternative to use features inside IBM Worklight Developer to allow us to deploy to external worklight server for testing environment ?

Answer (score 1):

You can use `Run AS --> Build for Remote Server` option to build for external worklight server.

It will give you WLAPP files in bin folder. Copy that and deploy that in Worklight server console.

For more info please use this [link](http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/wrklight/v6r0m0/index.jsp?topic=%2Fcom.ibm.worklight.help.doc%2Fdevref%2Ft_transporting_the_app.html)

Answer (score 0):

Find the following link for remote server deployment.
[Deploying in test and production environment](http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/wrklight/v6r0m0/topic/com.ibm.worklight.help.doc/devref/t_transporting_apps_and_adapters.html)